# Blender: Different constraint influence between multiple animations

Tags: animation, blender

I’m using multiple animation in blender (multiple Dope Sheets )

And I’m trying to animate an arm that have an inverse kinematic constraint attach to it. But sometimes I don’t want use it, so I set the influence to 0.

The “problem” when I do this it propagates the changes to all previous animations even if the channel is protected.

Anyone knows a some way to get around this situation?

Answer (score 0):

In blender *almost* any value can be keyframed, not just the location, rotation and scale of bones and objects. Any value that can be keyframed can also be controlled by [a driver](https://www.blender.org/manual/animation/drivers.html).

You can keyframe the influence value of the constraint the same as any other displayed value. Key it at 0.0 or 1.0 on the first frame and it will stay that way for the whole action. You can also keyframe it to turn on/off during the animation.

You can either <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> on a value and select insert keyframe or press <kbd>I</kbd> while the cursor is over the value.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is if I have two animations ( animantion1 and animantion2 ) that when I turn off IK constraint in animation2 it also turns the IK in the animantion1 and it mess up with the previous animation.

I discovery that what I was trying to accomplish is the same of use FK/IK in the same animation.

The solution is instead insert keyframes with location and rotation LocRot, insert the keyframes with Visual LocRot.

[Get the idea form this tutorial](https://vimeo.com/15309972) It explains  it around 14:42.